# How to extract title from string containing mix of special characters and words in R

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I have a long string containing a mix of words and characters.

```
<h4>        <a href="/forum?id=SyBPtQfAZ">          Improving Discriminator-Generator Balance in Generative Adversarial Networks        </a>          <a href="/pdf?id=SyBPtQfAZ" class="pdf-link" title="Download PDF" target="_blank"><img src="/static/images/pdf_icon_blue.svg"/></a>              </h4>
```

I need to extract only the title:

```
Improving Discriminator-Generator Balance in Generative Adversarial Networks
```

I know R has the ability to extract words between 2 characters, such as:

```
sub(">.*<", "", my_string)
```

But this obviously won't work here as there are a mix of many characters.

Comment: You should probably use an HTML parser here rather than a regex.

Comment: Agreed. Although this leaves me with multiple substrings within the longer string (see revised question). If there was a way to detect the longest sentence inside a string and extract it, that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using an HTML parser here.  That being said, the following one liner with `gsub` *might* work:

```
gsub(".*?<a href=[^>]*>\\s*(.*?)\\s*</a>.*", "\\1", input)
```

I say *might* because I make many assumptions, including that the title anchor tag is the first one, and that you don't have nested content.  In practice, you can try using an HTML/XML parser for greater control.

### Demo

Comment: Perfect! That does it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `u` is the URL from where you obtained this HTML, a HTML parsing solution might look like:

```
library(rvest)
titles <- read_html(u) %>%
  html_nodes("a[href^='/forum']") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  trimws()
```

This assumes that the `href` for titles starts with `/forum` and uses `trimws` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

[You should not rely on regex for parsing HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2890590) - it is very fragile and prone to breaking.  Consider using `rvest`.  You can take HTML from any source and `read_html()` to parse it.  `html_text()` extracts only the text elements and `trimws` trims excess whitespace that often exists in HTML.

```
library(rvest)
string = '<h4>        <a href="/forum?id=SyBPtQfAZ">          Improving Discriminator-Generator Balance in Generative Adversarial Networks        </a>          <a href="/pdf?id=SyBPtQfAZ" class="pdf-link" title="Download PDF" target="_blank"><img src="/static/images/pdf_icon_blue.svg"/></a>              </h4>'
read_html(string) %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  trimws()
```

Comment: See the answer given by @neilfws

Comment: @neilfws bases his answer on reading in a full webpage and extracting the node.  My answer demonstrates that you can apply the same process to just the string (if that string is being obtained from a source other than a URL).